# How can I create custom shapes?

Tags: garrys-mod

How can I make a custom shape out of 2 objects? I know you can *no collide* the two and then *weld* 'em together, but the work involved to position both objects perfectly is unbearable.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Use Easy Weld instead of Weld.

Long answer:

1. If you haven't yet, no collide the two objects.
2. If you haven't yet, select the Weld tool from the tool menu.
3. On the first object, right click where you want the center of the object's rotation to be.
4. Position your crosshair on the second object.  A ghost of the first object should appear for your convenience.  If it doesn't, try checking the context menu settings.
5. Once you have the ghost object where you want, hit the mouse button the tool description tells you to.
6. You should be able to rotate the object on an axis now.  Rotate it where you want, then hit the mouse button the tool description tells you to.
7. Done!  Remember to save the object as a dupe for future use.

Comment: I'm using precision tool atm, but it's hard to position objects when you want them inside eachother with no collide